# Bit wise AND to calculate largest power of two that divides 'n' - C++

Tags: c++11, bitwise-operators

While reading Binary indexed tree I came across the following expression that magically calculated the largest power of two that divides a given number 'n'

> `n&-n`

I'd like a formal argument why this expression is doing what it does. 
Also, there are many tricks like this using bitwise operator that might save us a lot of time and come in handy. Please list as many as you know. 

For example,  `1 << n`  gives two raised to power n.

Comment: If you write ```n&-n``` as ```n & -n``` now you have much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question,
I wasn't able to find a very sophisticated solution but this satisfied me
Let the highest power of two that divides `n` be 2<sup>k</sup>.
This means there are `k` zeroes after the last 1(if there none, it gives n=0 and n&-n is also zero, which is correct).

> `-n = ~n+1`, hence all digits in n are inverted except the last one and the following `k` zeroes.

Taking Bitwise AND will result in the last one followed by k zeroes, which is precisely 2<sup>k</sup>.
Some of the hacks using bitwise operators I found are:

> x | (1 << k) sets kth bit to one
>
> x & ~(1 << k) sets kth bit to zero
>
> x ^ (1 << k) inverts the kth bit
>
> x & (x−1) sets the last one bit of x to zero
>
> x &−x sets all the one bits to zero, except for the last one bit.
>
> positive number x is a power of two exactly when x & (x−1) = 0.
>
> The formula x | (x−1) inverts all the bits after the last one bit

These can be justified with similar proofs. I'll add more as I come across more.